# How to use CSV in mne.io.read_raw_fif()?

Tags: python, signals, google-colaboratory

I have a CSV file about EEG signals. I want to use his file with men package

so I try this code in colab:

```
import numpy as np
import mne
from mne.channels import make_standard_montage


from numpy import genfromtxt

my_data = genfromtxt('dataset.csv', delimiter=',',dtype=None)


# Some information about the channels
ch_names = ['CH 1', 'CH 2', 'CH 3']  # TODO: finish this list

# Sampling rate of the Nautilus machine
sfreq = 5000  # Hz

# Create the info structure needed by MNE
info = mne.create_info(ch_names, sfreq)

# Finally, create the Raw object
raw = mne.io.Raw(my_data, info)
# Plot it!
raw.plot()
```

this is error:

[image]
here I know my_data: it was (numpy.ndarray), and it should be with

> raw.fif, raw.fif.gz, raw_sss.fif, raw_sss.fif.gz, raw_tsss.fif,
> raw_tsss.fif.gz, or _meg.fif. If a file-like object is provided,
> preloading must be used, as [it mention here](https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.read_raw_fif.html).

So my question is, how can I convert CSV to one of these formats? is there any suggestion?

Thanks.

Comment: You can read the .csv, convert it to numpy array (depending on your .csv formatting, maybe pandas?), and then create an mne RAW object with mne.io.RawArray(data, info) with data.shape being (n_channels, n_times).

Comment: actually, mne.io.RawArray(data, info) needs a different format, it doesn't work with numpy array, see the error above. these the suitable format: raw.fif, raw.fif.gz, raw_sss.fif, raw_sss.fif.gz, raw_tsss.fif, raw_tsss.fif.gz, or _meg.fif. but I don;t know how to convert the csv file.

Comment: As someone who is working with this exact function on an online EEG system, acquiring a window in a numpy array shaped (n_times, n_channels) and then passing it to MNE with mne.io.RawArray(data.T, info), I can assure you that it works. Note that I used mne.io.RawArray() and not mne.io.Raw().

Comment: https://mne.tools/stable/generated/mne.io.RawArray.html -- Raw object from numpy array.